# WCF + EF6 Prevent enum from referenced assembly to be serialized

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, serialization, enums

I have an assembly E that is referenced in Assemblies F & WS, WS being my webservice.

In E, I have a public enum type that is used by F & WS, but when generating the proxy in assembly F, the WebService regenerates the enum members, resulting in an ambigous reference error between Assembly F & WS.

I tried to specify the enum in the ExcludedTypes section of Reference.svcmap, but it is still being generated.

How can I exclude the enum(s) without making too much modifications to my code?

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly what you looking, but when you referencing web service go to Advanced and check `Reuse types in all referenced assemblies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' (in Service Reference 'Advanced' tab).

Comment: Finally it seems to work; because of a bad dll being referenced, I had to clean and regenerate the solution and then update the Web service reference, then it was ok.

Comment: Yes, and make sure that the type is actually in a DLL that is directly referenced by your project and not referenced by another reference